# qt designer push button default not working

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

my button default property wont work (when I press enter the button wont press)it shows me that this button is default by a solid line around it but it will only works when the focus is on it although I have set it to be default not auto default
this button is inside a tab widget I don`t know if that is a problem or not?
additionally before this I was always using default buttons on Q Dialog but this one is on a Q Main Window maybe that is the problem

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [the reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpushbutton.html#default-prop), a default button works only in a dialog.(You can be certain that by reading [the implementation](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/v6.5.1/src/widgets/dialogs/qdialog.cpp#L682).)

It's a bad UX if you put a default button on the main window. But if you insist on that, you can embed a dialog into a main window like this.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Dlg(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        box = QVBoxLayout(self)

        box.addWidget(QLineEdit())

        b = QPushButton('b', default=True)
        b.clicked.connect(lambda: print('clicked b'))
        box.addWidget(b)

class MainWin(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setCentralWidget(Dlg())

app = QApplication([])
main_win = MainWin()
main_win.show()
app.exec()
```